# Can my RPi B+ control a Apto® CAN-BUS Shield for Arduino?

Tags: can-bus

I would like to get started into the CAN-BUS world and therefore I am looking for some CAN boards.
I came across two of them.

- [Pican](http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/pican-canbus-board-for-raspberry-pi-p-1196.html)
- [Apto for Arduino](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00XQ4HGH2/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A3T5GUAG34H3Q8)

The second one would be the best from a "commercial perspective", however it explicitly says (for Arduino).
Is it possible to control it via Raspberry Pi B+ too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to purchase a converter from Arduino Shield to Raspberry Pi.

Here is one for you on [Amazon.de](http://www.amazon.de/RPi-Shield-Bridge-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-Adapter/dp/B00I4ME33G/ref=sr_1_2?s=ce-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1450433878&sr=1-2&keywords=arduino%20shield%20raspberry%20pi), but feel free to Google and choose a different one.

Comment: @user22948 did you ever find something?